# Is there a way to add such folder in Android project that do no get compiled up to **apk**

Tags: android, eclipse

I was looking for a way to add some such folder in my Android Project that do no get compiled up to my `apk` file.

**Why I need it :-**

> We need to maintain proper documentation for project (*that actually
>   everybody needs to ;) nothing new*),
>
> but I find it very irritating to look out for that documentation
>   folder again and again.

.

> I am open for any way i can make dcocumentain folder easily **one
>   click accessible** (I am already doing it thru taskbar sortcut. ) But
>   I want it to get the ease of version control thru  Eclipse likewise we
>   do it  for our project

**IDE** :- `Eclipse`

Comment: Depends on your IDE.  In Android Studio/IDEA, I can right click and mark the folder as "excluded".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got a way myself :-

> I had an **idea** that if I create a folder in my application project with
>   some anonymous name that actually android has not listed in its
>   directories ("I am talking about the default one like "res", "src",
>   "anim"......)

**Then either it should "raise an error" or should "ignore" it while compiling to form apk file**

luckily it ignores any such folder. now i can put all the documentation in my project.

**NOTE:-**

My answer empirically driven

> I had tested it by creating a "**Docs**" folder and then copied  **1 GB** of
>   random data (includes almost all type of files we came across from
>   multimedia to zipped ones).
>
> Then I build the apk and the size of the apk was in-effective of all
>   this..
>
> but when i copied the same data to assets it was showing a huge change
>   in size of my apk file..

Answer (score 0):

Consider using Javadoc in addition or, if possible, instead of any other documentation.